# ¿Cómo relacionar un modelo en Django con User?

Tags: django, django-models

Necesito relacionar un modelo, al cual he llamado Cliente con el usuario predefinido por Django.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No olvides que el código debe ir _como texto, con formato_. ¿Cuál es el problema específico que estás teniendo? No olvides mejorar tu pregunta para que no suene a un [ticket para desarrollo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

en la documentaciòn de django puedes leer acerca de cómo extender con atributos de tu interes el modelo predefinido en User:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

La misma propone dos alternativas dependiendo tus necesidades, la primera es extender la clase AbstractUser de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

    class Cliente(AbstractUser):
```

La segunda aproximación supone una relaciòn 1 a 1 con tus atributos actuales:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Cliente(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```